# Concatenation in C #

Tags: c#, string, concatenation

I have the following piece of code:

```
byte [] bytes;
string one_simbol;

bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes (n.GetPixel (x, y). R + n.GetPixel (x, y). G + n.GetPixel (x, y). B);
one_simbol = Encoding.GetEncoding (1251). GetString (bytes, 0, bytes.Length);

// Always in one_simbol any one character
// We do the following

full_text + = one_simbol + one_simbol + one_simbol;
```

No matter how much I add these characters, even if they are different ends up being stored in the variable full_text only 1 character, the first that has been added

Comment: @Rawling - Fair enough. Threw me off.

Answer (score 7):

You should *absolutely* not be using `Encoding` like this. Your byte array *isn't* encoded text - so why try to act as if it is? You've got arbitrary binary data, so you should use something like base64 (or perhaps hex) instead to ensure round-tripping:

```
string text = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```

That way you'll be able to reverse the data, which I assume is what you want.

Now as to why your concatenation supposedly isn't working: I strongly suspect it *is*, but that due to control characters etc in your text, you aren't able to see it correctly. Try printing out `full_text.Length`, and I suspect it will equal `one_simbol.Length * 3`.